# adding and multiplying COUNT() of several tables

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

Is it possible to add and multiply the count of different tables where the id is the same?
Imagine:

```
Table_1       Table_2    Table_3
id            id         id
1             1          1
1             2          2
2             2          3
3             2          3
3             2          3
3             3          3
```

So that the end result would be this table with 2 columns:

```
id        (COUNT(Table_1.id) + 2*COUNT(Table_2.id) + 3*COUNT(Table_3.id))
1                                   7
2                                   12
3                                   17
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I understood you correctly but give this a try,

```
SELECT a.ID,
       a.aa + (2 * b.bb) + (3 * c.cc)
FROM
  (
    SELECT ID, COUNT(*) aa
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY ID
  ) a LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT ID, COUNT(*) bb
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY ID
  ) b ON a.ID = b.ID
  LEFT JOIN
  (
    SELECT ID, COUNT(*) cc
    FROM table3
    GROUP BY ID
  ) c ON a.ID = c.ID
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1b3a/4)

Comment: @AndreKR what if records on table1 don't have matches on other tables? it will surely won;t show on the list.

Comment: What if records in Table_3 don't have matches on other tables?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, counts_1.number + 2 * counts_2.number + 3 * counts_3.number
FROM
(SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS number FROM Table_1 GROUP BY id) AS counts_1
JOIN
(SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS number FROM Table_2 GROUP BY id) AS counts_2 USING (id)
JOIN
(SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS number FROM Table_3 GROUP BY id) AS counts_3 USING (id)
```

Note that this solution requires that every id exists at least once in each of the tables, otherwise it will be left out of the result. Changing this would require a FULL OUTER JOIN that MySQL is incapable of. There are [ways around that limitation](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/), though.